# Print array value instead of its name

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

```
#! /bin/bash
array_1=(1 3 5)
array_2=(7 9 3)
array_3=(0 -1 3)    

for i in {1..3}; do
        array=array_$i
        echo "${array[@]}"
done
```

I'm printing "array_1", "array_2" and "array_3" instead of its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the full variable name plus `[@]` as a string, then get the elements with [`${!var}` indirect expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/indirect-return-of-all-elements-in-an-array). It's funky, but putting `[@]` in the string rather than in the expansion is the way to go.

```
#!/bin/bash
array_1=(1 3 5)
array_2=(7 9 3)
array_3=(0 -1 3)    

for i in {1..3}; do
    array="array_$i[@]"
    echo "${!array}"
done
```